# Специфическое разделение строк на отдельные строки

Tags: java, строки

У меня есть одна большая строка с большим кол-вом предложений с разным кол-вом слов. Мне надо разбить эту строку на линии по минимум 60 символов, но чтобы разбивалось только по пробелам. Я знаю, что в Guava есть класс Splitter. Но если я использую Splitter.fixedLength(60), то строка будет разбиваться по буквам. Если же использовать Splitter.on(" "), то каждое слово выделится в отдельную строку. Как лучше это сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
private String justify(String s, int limit) {
    StringBuilder justifiedText = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder justifiedLine = new StringBuilder();
    String[] words = s.split(" ");
    for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        justifiedLine.append(words[i]).append(" ");
        if (i+1 == words.length || justifiedLine.length() + words[i+1].length() > limit) {
            justifiedLine.deleteCharAt(justifiedLine.length() - 1);
            justifiedText.append(justifiedLine.toString()).append(System.lineSeparator());
            justifiedLine = new StringBuilder();
        }
    }
    return justifiedText.toString();
}
```